# K3S on AWS with nfs-csi not starting

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, nfs, k3s

Our Kubernetes cluster is based on k3s and we are using nfs-csi to mount storage across all our nodes.

When we run our solution on azure vm (k3s) everything is working as expected out-of-the-box.
The weird thing is when we are trying to run the same solution with the same values and the same nfs-csi on AWS we are getting the pods stuck with ContainerCreating status and the describe output show that the NFS can't be mounted.

> MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "nfs" : rpc error: code =
> DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded

From AWS I was told that they are not supporting k3s and that I need to use Amazon Linux and not ubuntu (on AWS)...
It looks very strange since in Azure it's working well.

Any ideas?